# Dynamic 365 CRM openEntityForm or windows.open with html as parameter

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, crm

I have email template which I 'parse' and send (from current Lead form) as a parameter to new email form (from JavaScript).

```
var parameters = {};
parameters["subject"] = 'Subject name';
parameters["description"] = '<font face="Tahoma, Verdana, Arial" size=2 style="display:inline;"><br></font>';

Xrm.Utility.openEntityForm("email", null, parameters);
```

or

```
let serverUrl = "https://companyname.crm4.dynamics.com";

let extraqs = "subject=Subject name";
extraqs += '&description=<font face="Tahoma, Verdana, Arial" size=2 style="display:inline;"><br></font>';

let targetUrl = serverUrl.replace(/\/$/, "") + "/main.aspx?etn=email&pagetype=entityrecord&extraqs=" + encodeURIComponent(extraqs);
parent.open(targetUrl);
```

or

```
let serverUrl = "https://companyname.crm4.dynamics.com";

let extraqs = 'subject=' + encodeURIComponent('Subject name');
extraqs += '&description=' + encodeURIComponent('<font face="Tahoma, Verdana, Arial" size=2 style="display:inline;"><br></font>');

let targetUrl = serverUrl.replace(/\/$/, "") + "/main.aspx?etn=email&pagetype=entityrecord&extraqs=" + extraqs;
parent.open(targetUrl);
```

I get error every time I want to send anything look like as html tag (anything contains '<' or '>' sign).

Is it possible at all, to send my html markup trough the parameters, is there any security issue with this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is solvable with `encodeURIComponent` / `decodeURIComponent` like this:

```
parameters["description"] = encodeURIComponent('<html here>');
```

And on the other side:

```
var description = decodeURIComponent(incomingParameterHere);
```

In this fashion your HTML passes through as a simple string. This can(should?) be applied to all strings being passed around via JS.

Comment: I thought that 'Xrm.Utility.openEntityForm' does that before send parameters. Thank you very much.

Comment: I add above in question one more example with 'window/parent.open' instead of 'Xrm.Utility.openEntityForm' because with openEntityForm cannot open entity in new tab only with window.open it is possible. Do you maybe know why it does not work (there is encodeURIComponent(extraqs)) ?

Answer (score 0):

What I found what that for description to contain html tags it needs the pId and pType values defined (wonder if this is by design or a bug)

```
var entityFormOptions = {
    entityName: "email"
};

var emailFormParams = {
    subject: "subject",
    description:"<p1>html here</p1>",
    //sets the regarding - needed for description to be html
    pId:"{GUID}",
    pType:112 //objectTypeCode for the party
};

Xrm.Navigation.openForm(entityFormOptions, emailFormParams);
```