# In Dynamics 365 CRM , how to put an email button on Contact details page?

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

Currently, in the Dynamics 365, to send an email we have go to activities --> email and then search for the contact to populate the address and then send the email.

I would like to put an email button on contact details page that takes me to this email form page. And I would like to suppress the cc and bcc fields on this form while automatically populating the To field based on the contact email.

Answer (score 0):

Approach 1:

1. Start with ribbon workbench to add a button in contact form [Ribbon/Command bar customization]
2. Add a JS command to open customized email form (cc, bcc removed) [Form customization + web resource]
3. You may need to pass Params while opening form like contact Id to prepopulate the regarding & to fields [Client side coding]

Approach 2:

1. Add a Subgrid of Emails in contact form [Form customization]
2. By Out-of-Box functionality, on click of (+) in subgrid menu bar - customized Email form will open with the regarding field preset as current contact [Form customization + OOB]
3. On form load of email, do some JS to set the [To field](https://neilparkhurst.com/2015/10/22/javascript-set-activity-party/) based on Regarding contact

Comment: your approach #1 seems most promising. I have created a duplicate of email form by using "save as " and removed CC and BCC fields. However, I cant figure out how to invoke code js to invoke this form and also how to populate the To field from the js

Comment: You can Search in internet. Start with https://stackoverflow.com/q/47416197/7920473. If this answer helped you for the broad question, upvote/mark it.

Answer (score 0):

If you install [ClickDimensions](http://clickdimensions.com/), you'll gain the option to `Send Email` on the default contact form, straight from the ribbon:

[image]